# Exclude using NOT LIKE unless variable present

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I am working on the migration of a stock based retail database.

When a product is a one off order the product code has a leading CO

We do not want to take the CO products across unless they are currently, in stock, on stock order or on customer order

I have tried the following and some CASE variations but to no avail

```
SELECT prdcod,
stkqty,
ordqty,
csoqty
FROM prdtbl
WHERE prdtbl.prdcod NOT LIKE '*%'
AND (prdcod NOT LIKE 'CO%' AND stkqty >0 AND ordqty >0 AND csoqty >0);
```

The NOT LIKE 'CO%' function needs to occur only when the stock qty, ordqty and csqty are all less then 1/ greater than 0, we need to retain the product if there is a qty in any of those columns.

An example data set is in the link below (without the last query line above). I am hoping to exclude lines 19 and 20 in this situation.

https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/qTE1Av9i0x0BSjv_xAMj18bhX14cNWQPW9iYIBtpk4a6imhFiMRd7jRjFim_vPHxzcgu9h4xU9t8opA=w1920-h1070

Any thoughts are appreciated!

** I still need to return normal product codes which may have 0 stock or order qtys

Comment: If those are numbers (`stkqty`, etc), don't put them in quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `or` for the condition

```
SELECT prdcod,
stkqty,
ordqty,
csoqty
FROM prdtbl
WHERE prdtbl.prdcod NOT LIKE '*%'
AND (prdcod NOT LIKE 'CO%' 
     or (prdcod like 'CO%' 
         AND (stkqty >0 
              OR ordqty >0 
              OR csoqty >0
             )
         )
     )
```

So what this says is:

Exclude all those like 'CO%', except if one of the qty values is greater than 0